# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2], but path is correct

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-not-found

I ran the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\ПеКа476\Desktop\Matrices\118_OG_6-sec_imcoh_sensors_4-8.xlsx')
print(data)
```

but this yielded an error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\ПеКа476\\Desktop\\Matrices\\118_OG_6-sec_imcoh_sensors_4-8.xlsx'
```

[image]

[image]

The path is fully correct: `C:\Users\ПеКа476\Desktop\Matrices\118_OG_6-sec_imcoh_sensors_4-8.xlsx` — I take it from the file description. Can anyone please spot the error? I was trying to read other questions about this problem, but they report the same problem: unfull file path. But in my situation, the file path is almost correct.

Comment: You are sure sure about the extension?

Comment: try single forward slash?

Comment: @LV98 should not be an issue.

Comment: Do you have the rights on those files ?

Comment: @SayandipDutta what do u mean? xlsx? I think that this is the extension of excels files, no?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Yes, I have

Comment: Go to view, and check show extensions. It could be `xlsx` or `xls` or `csv` or number of different things, it is better to check. You can also find that info in `properties`. If I had to guess, I would say it is `xls` judging bt tge Type hint in your directory.

Comment: @LV98 just F4? If I do it, I cannot see any file addresses

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Permissions would cause a different error.

Comment: @SayandipDutta If I try `csv`  format I see this error: `XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'0.000000'`

Comment: Open the excel file. Click File. Go to "Info" (Infromaticija). And click "copy path" (Kopirevai path).

Comment: It is not about trial and error, you need to check what the extension actually is, if it is `csv` read with `pd.read_csv`.

Comment: @SayandipDutta You are right, thx) 
All is work now

Comment: @LV98 yes, thx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the excel file.

Click File.

Go to "Info"

Click "Copy Path"

This ensures copying the correct path, including the correct extension.